# Datasets deletion based on period in dataset name

Tags: sas

I have a library that have tables with name as "tablename_YYYYMM".I want to write a script which loops through all the folders on the disk and deletes tables older than 4 years. Table deletion should be done on the date implied by the filename (dataset name)and individual querying of the dataset is not required. the deleted dataset name and deletion time is stored. I have attached the tables structure. I have the below code but it didn't worked as expected. [Image of table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKW06.png)

```
PROC CONTENTS DATA=WORK._ALL_ OUT=contents NOPRINT; RUN;
 
 proc sort data=work.contents;
 by memname;
 run;
 
 DATA work.deleted;
 length libname $15. time 8;
 format time datetime20.;
 RETAIN libname memname time;
 SET contents(KEEP=LIBNAME MEMNAME) end=eof;
 by memname;
 where length(scan(memname, -1, '_')) = 6 and  input(scan(memname, -1, '_') || '01',?yymmdd8.) > intnx('year', today(), -10, 's');
 if first.memname;
    time = datetime();
 if _n_ = 1 then call execute('proc sql;');
 call execute(catx(' ', 'drop table', catx('.', libname, memname), ';'));
 if eof then do;
 call execute('quit;');
 
 
 end;
 
 RUN;
```

Comment: Do you want to scan every single folder and subfolder on your machine, or just a specific library?

Comment: @StuSztukowski just specific libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. I would do it slightly differently, see this approach.

```
*make fake data;
data demo_201501;
    set sashelp.class;

data random_201803;
    set sashelp.class;

data help_202004;
    set sashelp.class;
run;

*get list of tables;

data _table_list;
    set sashelp.vtable;
    where libname='WORK' and substr(memname, 1, 1) ne "_";
    cutoff_date=put(intnx('year', today(), -4, 'b'), yymmn6.);
    date_file=scan(memname, 2, "_");

    if date_file < cutoff_date;
    keep libname memname nobs cutoff_date date_file;
run;

*delete via proc datasets;
data _null_;
    set _table_list end=eof;

    if _n_=1 then
        do;
            call execute('proc datasets lib=work nolist nodetails;
delete');
        end;
    call execute(" "||memname||" ");

    if eof then
        call execute(";run;quit;");
run;
```

Regarding your code specifically, your WHERE condition is incorrect.

The INPUT function isn't correctly parsing the date and you're using 10 years not 4 as specified in your question. The comparison is also backwards, you're keeping files that are more recent rather than ones that are older.

From your code, this seems to work:

```
 DATA work.deleted;
 length libname $15. time 8;
 format time datetime20.;
 RETAIN libname memname time;
 SET contents(KEEP=LIBNAME MEMNAME) end=eof;
 by memname;

 
 where length(scan(memname, -1, '_')) = 6 and  input(scan(memname, -1, '_'),? yymmn6.) < intnx('year', today(), -4, 'b');
  if first.memname; 
    time = datetime();
 if _n_ = 1 then call execute('proc sql;');
 call execute(catx(' ', 'drop table', catx('.', libname, memname), ';'));
 if eof then do;
 call execute('quit;');
 
 
 end;
 
 RUN;
```

EDIT: conditionally doing this for different types of data using the IF.
Basically makes sure the _TABLE_LIST data set has the list of tables you want to drop and you can modify the IF statement.

```
data _table_list;
    set sashelp.vtable;
    where libname='WORK' and substr(memname, 1, 1) ne "_";
    cutoff_date_data=put(intnx('year', today(), -4, 'b'), yymmn6.);
    cutoff_date_rest=put(intnx('year', today(), -4, 'b'), yymmn6.);
    date_file=scan(memname, 2, "_");

    if (scan(memname, 1, "_") = "DATA" and date_file < cutoff_date_data) 
    OR (scan(memname, 1, "_") ne "DATA" date_file < cutoff_date_rest);

    keep libname memname nobs cutoff_date date_file;
run;
```

Comment: Then flip the > sign.

Comment: "deletes tables older than 4 years" is your original statement.

Comment: thanks reeza the code works.

Comment: suppose my table structure is like belowdata_202011
data_201312
data_201401
data_201702
data_201805
trial_202011
trial_201902
trial_201111
trial_201703
dummy_202101
dummy_202005
dummy_201806
dummy_201709
and  i want to delete tables older than 7 years whose name starts with "data_yyyymm" and rest of the tables will be deleted older than 4 years. whta to change for it in the logic

Comment: Added the IF condition example.